# Integration by substitution: $\int(\frac{x^2}{x^2 - 4})dx = \cdots$

Tags: integration, substitution

I've been trumped by this integral.

I'm doing integration by substitution - for the first time.

I was given the task of finding:
$$\int(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x} )dx$$ using $u^2 = x^2 +4$

I've ended up with
$$\int(\frac{u^2}{u^2 - 4})du$$
I don't know where to go now...

I tried using the formula $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\ln{f(x)}$:
$$\frac{2}{u}\int(\frac{2u}{u^2-4})du = \frac{2}{u}\cdot\ln({u^2-4})=\frac{2\ln{(u^2-4)}}{u}$$ however this isn't the correct answer.

I also tried reformatting to:
$$\int(\frac{u^2}{(u-2)(u+2)})du$$
However this leaves me in a different hole.

I have a feeling somewhere during simplification I've missed a step; or, there's an identity for $\frac{x^2}{x^2 - b^2}$.

I've ran into a similar problem in a different question, resulting in:
$$\int(\frac{4}{u^2-4})du$$

Both are in the form $\frac{a^2}{a^2 - b^2}$, so I must be missing something - I coincidentally read earlier today, coincidences are rare in mathematics, often you find you're missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$\frac{u^2}{u^2-4}=\frac{u^2-4+4}{u^2-4}=1+\frac4{u^2-4}=1+\frac1{u-2}-\frac1{u+2}$$

Partial fraction decomposition, here, is pretty simple.

$$\frac4{(u-2)(u+2)}=\frac a{u-2}+\frac b{u+2}$$

for some unknown $a,b$.  Multiply both sides by $(u-2)(u+2)$ to get that

$$4=a(u+2)+b(u-2)$$

Setting $u=2$, we get

$$4=4a\implies a=1$$

Setting $u=-2$, we get

$$4=-4b\implies b=-1$$

Thus,

$$\frac4{(u-2)(u+2)}=\frac1{u-2}-\frac1{u+2}$$

---

Alternatively, one may notice that

$$\begin{align}\frac4{(u-2)(u+2)}&=\frac{(u+2)-(u-2)}{(u-2)(u+2)}\\&=\frac{u+2}{(u-2)(u+2)}-\frac{u-2}{(u-2)(u+2)}\\&=\frac1{u-2}-\frac1{u+2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Is $\frac{4}{u^2-4} = \frac{1}{u-2} - \frac{1}{u+2}$ something you've learned or worked out?

Comment: @Tobi Try combining the fractions on the right side.  I'm updating to explain more.

Comment: @Tobi Fully updated, explaining how one derives such forms.

Comment: What a complicated question, from start to finish.

Comment: @Tobi How about the last line now?

Comment: I don't think I'd ever naturally notice that sort of refactoring while doing a question - especially with a time limit. I guess it's something I may pick up with practice.

Comment: Perhaps when they give you that integration task, they assume you already know about the method of partial fractions.

Comment: This integration stuff is ahead of partial fractions, so the candidate should know about it. However, because it's so far ahead, using partial fractions didn't come across my mind. Also I hadn't even come to the conclusion that $\frac{u^2}{u^2-4} = 1 +\frac{4}{(u^2-2)(u^2+2)}$.

Comment: @Tobi You should eventually learn the method of PFD.  I can't imagine you doing these fractions easily without it.

Comment: What exactly is PFD?

Comment: @Tobi [Partial Fraction Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)

Comment: @Tobi Actually, the wikipedia link looks scary.  I'd look up YouTube tutorials on the subject.

Comment: Oh, partial fractions; yeah, I've covered that. The problem is I hadn't concluded that $\frac{u^2}{u^2-4} = 1 + \frac{4}{u^2 - 4}$ so I wouldn't have had any reason to use them.

Comment: @Tobi O_O well now you say that -_- XD

Comment: There's even more work with $ln$ simplifcation after all of this. This question is just *$"%...

Answer (score 1):

This is an "improper" rational expression.  Do long division, or write the numerator as $x=u^2-4+4$ so that your integrand is $1+\frac{4}{u^2-4}.$
Then use partial fractions to write the proper rational expression as
$\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x+2}$.

Comment: Coupled with the work done prior, it seem's like an inexplicable amount of work for 4 marks.

Comment: It's not that bad.  Partial fractions is a standard technique, which should be automatic when trying to integrate a rational function.  You make one u-substitution and then hit it with "the usual".  Done.  Maybe 4 marks means little, but the education it represents is priceless.